# How to fix position of the element relative to window size

Tags: html, css

I have a single image (a checkmark) on the page and I want to fix its position when the user resizes the browser or go fullscreen.

As you can see here the image is moving around the page when I try to resize the browser:(image is the checkmark)

[image]

And when I resize the browser again:
[image]

The desired result is to fix the position of the image **like that play button in the middle of the page** that moves relative to the window.

Here is  the CSS of the image:

Note: I need those viewport units for some complicated reason! and the absolute positioning is prefered.

```css
#Image{
  position: absolute;
  max-width:10%; 
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 78vh;
  left:26.5vw;
  z-index: 1000;

}
```

```html
<img id="Image" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Changed.png"/>
```

**Update:** using this seems to work fine but the image resizes Non-proportional:

```
#correctImage{
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.2, 0.2); 
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

**Update 2:** Here is the link to download the zip files to test the code in the browser (Chrome is preferred). The HTML code to modify is in `story_html5.html` lines 22 - 27 and the CSS code is in `correctImageStyle.css`.

The desired behavior is just resizing and repositioning of the checkmark image like the play button in the center of the page.

http://s6.picofile.com/d/8381556034/1ef7bc07-eea8-4e9e-8bd8-57214a1e7ef8/Untitled1_Storyline_output.zip

Comment: can you please share your code via a codepen or something so we don't have to write the entire thing.

Comment: Where you want to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the max-width: 10%; to width: 10%

```css
#Image{
  position: absolute;
  width:10%; 
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 78vh;
  left:26.5vw;
  z-index: 1000;

}
```

```html
<img id="Image" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Changed.png"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... plus one... but it doesn't work too...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to force your image to always be on the middle of the screen with:

```css
#Image{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: scale(0.2); 
height: 100vh; 
width: 100vw;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<img id="Image" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Changed.png"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... plus one... but it doesn't work ...

Comment: @SaraRee your own solution seems appropriate, but `transform: scale` property resizes the image directly based on your `<body>` element size.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```css
html,body,* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
img.image {
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: grey;

}
.logo {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image"/>
  <img class="logo absolute" id="Image" src="https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Changed.png"/>
</div>
```

With ::after

```css
html,body,* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/test/Changed.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  z-index: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the working answer... plus one...The width works fine but the height doesn't seem to work... I'm trying to find the solution...

Comment: by height you mean if I decrease the window height?

Comment: please give me 5 minutes to provide you a sample code that you can test it there....

Comment: @SaraRee I don't think many people will download unknown files... please use something like codepen or jsfiddle to share your code